# One word for "hiding an obvious fact"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there one word for "hiding an ***obvious*** fact". For e.g.

> I will not be **__** about the fact that this task is difficult.

Some words that come to my mind are "deny" or "pretend", but they don't necessarily imply that there is something *obvious* about the thing being denied.

For e.g.

> I will not deny the fact that this task is difficult (doesn't imply
>   that the task is *obviously* difficult)

Another example -

> She kept mum about her affair with him, but it was obvious to
>   everyone.
>
> She was **__** about her affair with him.

Comment: [Paper over](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/paper+over)?

Comment: "[**Elephant in the room**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant_in_the_room)" is related also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I will not *"gloss over"* the fact that this task is difficult.**

Though I would not want to miss an opportunity to use @FumbleFingers' "obfuscating", people frequently refer to the behavior of omitting discussion of an obvious or uncomfortable topic or detail by admitting to "glossing over" those specific issues.

> Definition of "gloss over" from the Cambridge Dictionaries Online:
>
> "to avoid considering something, such as an embarrassing mistake , to make it seem not important, and to quickly continue talking about something else"

Answer (score 3):

For both of your example sentences, [*discreet*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/discreet) was the first word I thought of. I feel it implies that although a thing may be public knowledge, you are not the type to talk about it.

Answer (score 1):

***Turn a blind eye*** is an apt phrase.

turn a blind eye (to someone or something)
Fig. to ignore something and pretend you do not see it. The usher turned a blind eye to the little boy who sneaked into the theater. How can you turn a blind eye to all those starving children?

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/turn+a+blind+eye

Answer (score 0):

An adjective that,  I think, may fit your sentences : [ingenuous](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Ingenuous):

> naive, artless, or innocent.

- I will not be ingenuous about the fact that the task is difficult.
- She was ingenuous about her affair with him.

Answer (score 0):

Per @ermanen's comment, probably the most common idiomatic usage for ignoring or denying something *obvious* is [*[not mentioning the] **elephant in the room***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant_in_the_room).

If that's considered too "informal" in some contexts, OP might consider...

> *"She was [obfuscating](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/obfuscate) about her affair"*
>   (She was evasive, making information about the affair *obscure, unclear, unintelligible*)

...but I don't think that (or any other alternatives) would convey any sense that the topic being avoided was particularly *obvious* (except insofar as you wouldn't bother being "evasive" about something which wasn't *already known* - you simply wouldn't bring it up in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

I would state it this way:

> I will be transparent about the fact that this task is difficult.